# Java/Processing is that possible ? void hello(void funktion)

Tags: java, processing

Hey guys i got a fast question, is that possible in Java or Processing ?

```
void hello(void bye)
{

 // 

}
```

Comment: `void` is not a valid parameter type, so no.

Comment: `void` simply means the method does not return anything. It should not be used in a method's parameters. If you don't want to accept any parameters, you would simply write `void hello(){//your code here}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Java 8 you can use a [lambda](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

With Processing, you can use an **anonymous class** that **implements a functional interface**. Something like this:

```
interface DoFunction{
   void do();
}

void hello(DoFunction function){
   function.do();
}

void setup(){
   hello(new DoFunction(){
      void do(){
         println("here");
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: Hey, i tried it a few times :) but i get all the time an error ? could you look over my error message ? I dont know what wrong :/ tried to make it abstract but didnt work either ... thx

Comment: @genar What error are you getting? Edit your question to include your updated code and the full text of the error message, then let me know when you post the edit.

Comment: Fixed it now, the problem was that there wasnt any public before void do ^^ thx for the help mate ;)